# onfocus, type, outfocus, count, deactive after time period

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have such a jQuery when a user can click in a text input box, where they type it appears in 'real-time' in a div [this part, I have no problem with] - however, I would like to offer the user to outfocus from the text input box for upto, say, 5 seconds. If the user re-onfocus they can continue writing and it appears 'real-time', otherwise if more than 5 seconds later, the 'realtime' function disappears (but can continue writing).

When the realtime function disappears - I would like an edit button to appear next to the div where they can edit it in the div. I guess a hidden input would be required.

I guess what I'm looking for is similar to how Wordpress allows you to write in a page title, where the title forms part of the URL.

For the realtime part, I know I could do the following (not sure though on the logic and time counting once the focus has been lost):

```
$('#entry').keyup(function(){
    // if < 5 sec
    var entry = $('#entry').val();
    $('#display').html(entry+'<input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit">');
    $('#hidden-display').val(entry); // hidden input

    // if > 5 sec
    // do nothing realtime; add edit button
    $('#display').html($('#hidden-display').val()+'<input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit">');
});
```

Then for editing:

```
$("#edit").click(function(){
    $('#display').html('<input type="text" id="update" name="update" value="'+$('#hidden-display').val()+'"><input type="button" id="save" value="Save"><input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel">')
});
$("#cancel").click(function(){
    $('#display').text($('#hidden-display').val());
});
$("#save").click(function(){
    var entry = $('#update').val();
    $('#display').html(entry+'<input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit">');
    $('#hidden-display').text(entry);
});
```

I know the above isn't quite right, as should be adding in some `live` parts, the part i'm struggling with is the outfocus count, then checking that when back in focus.

Any help would be appreciated, any solution would be highly welcomed - especially if far more efficient than my current working draft :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go and save the current timestamp on the blur event and check back on the focus event:

```
$("#entry").blur(function(){
    $(this).data("blurtime", (new Date()).getTime());
}).focus(function(){
    var timediff = (new Date()).getTime() - $(this).data("blurtime");
    if(timediff > 5000)
        //do something
});
```

Alternatively you could go the native JS way using `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`.

Also, instead of adding a button as plain html, I highly recommend having the edit button outside of the #display div.

```
<div id="display"></div>
<input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit" style="display:none">

$("#edit").show();
```

Of course you can add a wrapper div around them, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks - Something like http://jsfiddle.net/GVsZW/1/ ? Though I'm unsure why iIcan still type if longer than 5 seconds - but I guess function in function = bad, not fully sure how to implement